# File Lock in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, locking, hdfs

How to lock a .txt file in Hdfs path using scala.So that the other process cannot access the locked file until it unlocks the file.It need to be implemented using scala in hdfs.Can anyone help me with the detailed code.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such feature provided by HDFS. You can implement any form of distributed advisory locking on your own or move a file to another directory/change permissions to temporarily restrict access.

Comment: HDFS doesn't support file locks - what exactly are you trying to achieve? If you have Hadoop you also have ZooKeeper installed and you can use that for that

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the Hadoop concept, it is optimized for write once read many (WORM) operation. It means there will be many clients reading the same file and conceptually it would not be possible to lock any file. Moreover, while writing the file on HDFS file system, Name Node (or master node) will a take care of consistency so there is no need to lock the files. Hope this answer your question. If not, please elaborate your overall problem statement to find a better insight into the solutions approach or right platform.

Comment: Maxid.txt file contains the maxbatch id in it.I want to raed the id & increment the value .At the same time another process should not increment the value .When this process gets completed i need to unlock the file.So the other process can have acess to it. Finally i need to generate a lock on the file which i am trying to read.So that other simultaneous process cannot read it.I need to wait till it writes the max value to thta file.& unlock the file .so the next processs can gain access to it,

Comment: As I indicated that HDFS is WORM approach, you have to build an exclusive locking approach. Since all the Hadoop ecosystem projects which do the computation, generate a Job ID and you need to make sure that one JobID is working on this file, another Job id should not access it. You can maintain the lock flag in the global context (somewhere in  RDBMS) and your program can check if the flag is open for other Jobs or not before accessing the file, if the job is still running, the new job may not trigger.

Comment: @vijay If you intent to modify the data, some kind of DB would be better than plain files. Maybe **HBase** or **Cassandra** already provide a built-in lock.